# Return one record with the max value if there is multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I thought it would be cool to have a table that shows three pieces of data. Table Name, Table last updated, Table last queried (in any Form) and the last time the server was started up.

This is what I came up with,

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
last_user_update AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS Last_Update,
(SELECT MAX(Last_Used_Date)
FROM (VALUES
(last_user_seek), 
(last_user_scan), 
(last_user_lookup)) 
AS value(Last_Used_Date)) 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS Last_Used,
(SELECT [sqlserver_start_time] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS Vaules_From 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'DATABASENAME')
ORDER BY TableName ASC
```

The issue I’m trying to fix is I get multiple records back from some tables due to them have indexes.

I want to just return one record with the max value if there is multiple records.

Comment: Seems you shouldn't be using subqueries here but normal aggregation. You might, however, need to unpivot your data in the `FROM` instead.

Comment: Aside: It would help us help you if your query had some reasonable indentation.

Answer (score 0):

A slight refactor gives the following, which aggregates by `object_id`

```
select Object_Name(ix.object_id, ix.database_id) as TableName,
  Max(ix.last_user_update) at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Central Standard Time' as Last_Update,
  Max(v.lastused) at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Central Standard Time' as Last_Used,
  (select sqlserver_start_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Central Standard Time' from sys.dm_os_sys_info) as Values_From 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ix
cross apply (values(last_user_seek), (last_user_scan), (last_user_lookup))v(lastused)
where database_id = Db_Id('dbName')
group by database_id, object_id
order by TableName
```